# Android Service Recreate

Tags: android, service

I am writing an app to notify the user at preferred day and time (let's say every first day of each month)

I searched and read some posts that suggesting me to use `AlarmManager` with `BroadcastReceiver` and `Service`

It works but the `Service` seems to be created multiple times, the `Notification` shows randomly. I added `log.i()` to trace it. It received the on `BOOT_RECEIVED` or first started the `Service` by the app, **Init Service** and **Create Service** were logged, the notification is shown correctly and normally. After some times, the service was created once again without **destroy log** and the notification shows again.
Does it normal?

**Log**

```
02-23 20:17:15.235: I/CMP(19210): Init Service
02-23 20:17:15.235: I/CMP(19210): Start Service
02-23 20:17:15.285: I/CMP(19210): Create Service
02-23 20:17:15.295: I/CMP(19210): 10157
02-23 20:17:15.295: I/CMP(19210): ON START COMMAND
02-23 20:17:25.785: I/CMP(19210): action_notify
02-23 20:21:12.415: I/CMP(23666): Create Service
02-23 20:21:12.515: I/CMP(23666): 10157
02-23 20:21:12.525: I/CMP(23666): ON START COMMAND
02-23 20:21:22.515: I/CMP(23666): action_notify
```

The **Service** Class

```
public class AppService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i("CMP", "Create Service");
        Utility.scheduleNotification(this.getBaseContext());
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        Log.i("CMP", "ON START COMMAND");
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i("CMP", "Destroy Service");
        Utility.cancelScheduleNotification(getBaseContext());
    }
}
```

The **BroadcastReceriver**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Common.setSettings(context);
            if (Utility.isEnabledService(context)) {
                Utility.initService(context);
                Utility.startService(context);  
            }
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Utility.ACTION_NOTIFY)) {
            Log.i("CMP", "action_notify");
            Utility.genNotify(context, intent);
        }    
    }
}
```

Some functions

```
public static void scheduleNotification(Context context) {
    Common.setSettings(context);

    if (ScheduleTask.getAlarmManager() == null)
        ScheduleTask.initAlarmManager(context);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.Add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(Utility.ACTION_NOTIFY);
    intent.putExtra("Job", i);
    intent.putExtra("Name", name);
    intent.addCategory(String.format("Job_$1%s", name));
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, i, intent, PendingIntent. FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    ScheduleTask.getAlarmManager().set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
    Log.i("CMP", String.valueOf(pi.getCreatorUid()));
}

public static void genTimeSheetNotify(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
        .setContentTitle("Test Notify")
        .setContentText("Testing Notify")
        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
        .setVibrate(new long[] { 0, 100, 200, 300 })
        .setLights(0xff00ff00, 100, 100)
        .setContentIntent(pi)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .build();

    if (Notify.getNotificationManager() == null)
        Notify.initNotificationManager(context);

    Notify.getNotificationManager().notify(extras.getInt("Job"), notification);
}

public static void genTimeSheetNotify(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    // notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
        .setContentTitle("TimeSheet Submission")
        .setContentText(String.format("Timesheet of %1$s is due today.", extras.get("Name").toString()))
        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
        .setVibrate(new long[] { 0, 100, 200, 300 })
        .setLights(0xff00ff00, 100, 100)
        .setContentIntent(pi)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .build();

    if (Notify.getNotificationManager() == null)
        Notify.initNotificationManager(context);

    Notify.getNotificationManager().notify(extras.getInt("Job"), notification);
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the Android OS is killing and then restarting the service since you've used a Sticky Service

Comment: @AndyFaizan i guess it so. does it normal? if then i am considering adding some flag to indicate the appear of notification.

Comment: When the system is restarting the service, the intent is probably null. Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381165/android-alarmmanager-randomly-scheduling-notifications

Comment: @AndyFaizan i have checked to link you gave me. I think it works. Would you please post it as the answer and let me accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system is killing and then restarting the service (since it is sticky). Hence, the notification is created randomly. You need to check the intent for null in the onStartCommand() because when the system starts the service, the intent will be null.

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if(intent != null)
        {
             //create notification here
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your help.
And I think twice, as I pass the action to alermmanager, I think it is not necessary to keep the service run as start_stick. :)